# Get a running total of line changes to a file in Git

Tags: git

I'd like a way to get an idea of how much my local files have changed while I haven't committed.

Something like a "number of lines changed" I think would be helpful. I looked through the man page for `git status` and googled a lot but I'm not finding much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few options:

```
git diff --stat 

git diff --shortstat
```

If you wish to get statistics for a given file use this:

```
git log --numstat --oneline <Filename>
```

Comment: Beautiful! `watch --color git diff --color --stat`